# Is there a prescribed reading order for Gail Levine's Princess books?

Tags: suggested-order, gail-levine

Is there a prescribed reading order for Gail Levine's Princess books or are they all independent and not part of the single universe and can be read in arbitrary order?

(Ella Enchanted, Fairest, The Princess Tales, Bamarre, As you wish, Tale of Two castles, any other I missed)?

I'm OK with an order either based on content (book A and B are in same universe and refer to one another) or author-specified order, though her website doesn't contain any.

Comment: While I appreciate a question about Gail Levine's works, you really *must* know that [tag:princess-tutu] was the wrong tag.

Comment: @Adamant - it was a mis-click, but looked too funny to fix

Comment: *Stolen Magic* is a sequel to *Tale of Two Castles,* and probably should be read after it.

Answer (score 1):

The Princess Tales book series was released as a [single compendium](https://www.harpercollins.com/9780062253576/the-fairys-return-and-other-princess-tales) in 2014.

> Now, for the first time, the six beloved Princess Tales are together
>   in one magnificent volume:
>
> The high jinks begin in **The Fairy's Mistake**, which pokes fun at a
>   meddlesome fairy whose plans for good go terribly awry. In **The
>   Princess Test**, the author spoofs the notion that a pea can prove a
>   person's pedigree. **Princess Sonora and the Long Sleep** features a
>   genius of a princess, a hundred years of snooze, two princes, and a
>   flock of balding sheep! **Cinderella** is a boy in Cinderellis and the
>   Glass Hill, and the glass slipper is a glass hill. In **For Biddle's
>   Sake**, Parsley tries to forget her beloved prince and get used to life
>   as a Biddlebum Toad. The road to happily-ever-after isn't easy when a
>   baker's son and a princess fall in love in **The Fairy's Return**.

The other series you've mentioned are broadly independent of each other and should simply be read in their [published orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gail_Carson_Levine#Bibliography).

For the record, the novel "Fairest" is set in the same fictional universe as "Ellan Enchanted". Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairest_(novel))

> Fairest is a 2006 novel by Gail Carson Levine. It uses some plot
>   elements of the classic Snow White and set in the same world as Ella
>   Enchanted. The kingdom of Ayortha, the setting of the story, is the
>   neighboring kingdom of Kyrria, where Ella Enchanted was set and the
>   story makes several allusions to the previous work.

Comment: is there any citable evidence that the rest are indepdendent of each other?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To - I'm trying to find something in the reviews. Bear with me

Comment: I believe that Ella enchanted and fairest are in the same universe (the countries in the book are side by side iirc). Unfortunately, I don't have the books with me so I can't check.